# How to implement swipeRight and swipeLeft events in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe, hammer.js

This is the first time,I am implementing application in mobile.I am making Application using `javascript` and `html`.

I want to implement `swipeRight and swipeLeft` events.For this I goggled everyone suggesting to use either `jquery` or `hammer`.

I tried with both the plugins, I failed with both plugins.

Using Jquery(not working) :

step 1: copy pasted code form [this](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js) link and save the file and mention at the end of the html page.

step 2: run the following code

```
  $('#eleId').on('swiperight',function(){alert("swipeRight");})
```

Using Hammer(not working) :

step 1: copy pasted code form [this](https://github.com/lukaszlipinski/jquery.hammer/blob/master/jquery.hammer.min.js) link and save the file and mention at the end of the html page.

step 2: run the following code as per documentation

```
  $('#eleId').on('swipe',function(){alert("swipeRight");})
```

In this case,It's throwing an exception,while page loading time itself.

exception :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Hammer is not defined
```

How can I achieve my requirements.Please can anyone help me.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: The exception is not caused by the code you have posted. There is no reference at all to `Hammer`...

Comment: Hammer is not defined error suggests that Hammer.js is not loaded before you use the function.

Answer (score 0):

In Jquery the syntax is

```
 $("selector").on("swipeleft",function(event){...})
```

Check out [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_swipeleft.asp) - but your code looks right

why do you need the hammer.js?

Check out [this link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/touchevents2.shtml) and build the swipe event yourself in javascript.

(just in case link gets deleted here's the code)

```
<script>



 window.addEventListener('load', function(){

   var touchsurface = document.getElementById('touchsurface'),
  startX,
  startY,
  dist,
  threshold = 150, //required min distance traveled to be considered swipe
  allowedTime = 200, // maximum time allowed to travel that distance
  elapsedTime,
  startTime

 function handleswipe(isrightswipe){
  if (isrightswipe)
   touchsurface.innerHTML = 'Congrats, you\'ve made a <span style="color:red">right swipe!</span>'
  else{
   touchsurface.innerHTML = 'Condition for right swipe not met yet'
  }
 }

 touchsurface.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
  touchsurface.innerHTML = ''
  var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
  dist = 0
  startX = touchobj.pageX
  startY = touchobj.pageY
  startTime = new Date().getTime() // record time when finger first makes contact with surface
  e.preventDefault()

 }, false)

 touchsurface.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){
  e.preventDefault() // prevent scrolling when inside DIV
 }, false)

 touchsurface.addEventListener('touchend', function(e){
  var touchobj = e.changedTouches[0]
  dist = touchobj.pageX - startX // get total dist traveled by finger while in contact with surface
  elapsedTime = new Date().getTime() - startTime // get time elapsed
  // check that elapsed time is within specified, horizontal dist traveled >= threshold, and vertical dist traveled <= 100
var swiperightBol = (elapsedTime <= allowedTime && dist >= threshold && Math.abs(touchobj.pageY - startY) <= 100)
handleswipe(swiperightBol)
e.preventDefault()
}, false)

}, false)

</script>

<div id="touchsurface">Swipe Me</div>
```

Comment: Will that work cross browser, on windows touch devices as well as iOs and Android?

Comment: don't have apple anything to test it. works on Android